# Google Map object returned as null on certain devices

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am using the following code to initialize the google map object:

```
if (googleMap == null) {
             googleMap = ( (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

      }
```

It works fine but on certain devices the googleMap object is shown as null.How do i work around it?

I broke the single line code as:

```
FragmentManager fmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            Fragment fragment = fmanager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            SupportMapFragment supportmapfragment = (SupportMapFragment)fragment;
googleMap=supportmapfragment.getMap();
```

The last line `supportmapfragment.getMap()` is the one which returns null.

My xml file:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Store locator"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="40px" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200px"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_categories"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what devices are these?

Comment: Devices of android 2.3 and less than 2.6